# IMDB-API - reading the response in while loop not reading more than one line

Tags: java, api

I am calling the IMDB-Api from Java code. It makes successful connection to the IMDB api and also reads but for some reason it doesn't read more than one line.  I see the entire response in 'aline' variable. But the while loop gets executed only  once.. I wonder why?

```
import javax.accessibility.AccessibleTable;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader; 
import java.lang.ref.SoftReference;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
 import java.io.IOException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class APExamPractice {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
         HttpURLConnection aconnection = null;

         String urltext = "https://imdb-api.com/API/AdvancedSearch/keyxxx/?genres=action,adventure";
       try {
        URL aurl = new URL(urltext);

        aconnection = (HttpURLConnection)aurl.openConnection();

        aconnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        aconnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.29 Safari/537.36");

        aconnection.setDoInput(true);


        InputStream astream = aconnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader areader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(astream));

        StringBuilder aresponse = new StringBuilder();

        String aline = null;
        
        while((aline = areader.readLine())!=null){
             //I see the entire response in 'aline' variable. But the while gets executed only 
             once.. I wonder why?
            aresponse.append(aline);
            aresponse.append("/r");
        }
        areader.close();
        String aresult = aresponse.toString();
        System.out.println(aresult);


        JSONObject aobject = new JSONObject(aresult);

        String ratings= aobject.getString("imDb");
    }catch (MalformedURLException e){
        System.out.println("Malformed exception");
    }catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO exception");
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the output has more than one line?

Comment: *”I  see the entire response in 'aline' variable“* - okay, so why aren’t you using that? I’m assuming the response is JSON, so it’s probably not “pretty” formatted to reduce the size

Comment: The issue is the areader will have all the movies which got from API, in one line. How to read from that one line title and ratings of all movies.BufferedReader areader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(astream));